# What does よう at the end of the sentences mean?

Tags: meaning

I know that "verb without masu + よう" expresses one's will to do something or stimulating other person to do something.

But while I was trying to translate [the lyrics to Hitoshizuku by Nobuhiko Okamoto](http://down.hangame.co.jp/movie/pc/easy/kamihaji/lyrics/hitoshizuku.pdf), I found this:

> いつの日かぬくもりに触れる**よう**
>   祈り捧げ　ただよう

Can someone explain to me what it means here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have two different よう's here.

> いつの[日]{ひ}かぬくもりに[触]{ふ}れる**よう**
>
> [祈]{いの}り[捧]{ささ}げ　ただ**よう**

触れるよう = 触れるように = "**so that** I could touch", "**hoping to** touch".  The よう（に） expresses one's purpose or goal.

ただよう = [漂]{ただよ}う = "to drift", "to wander".  The よう just happens to be the ending of the verb ただよう in its dictionary form.

"Hoping to touch the warmth one day, I offer up prayers and drift about."